# encoding not working in style balise

Tags: css, twig

I'm working with symfony and in my controller I have something like that :

```
 $colors =" test > test2{
         color : #fff
         }";
 return $this->render(
        'Default/views/page.html.twig',
        array("colors" =>$colors)
       );
```

and in my twig I have :

```
 <style>
      {{ colors }}
 </style>
```

but the problem is instead of `>` I have `&gt;` so my style doesn't apply. 
But If I do `{{ colors }}` outside my `script` I have correctly the `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colors`var is escaped for security reason, you have to use `{{ colors|raw }}` if you are sure of what you are doing.

See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html